# SystemErr R 373846 [WebContainer : 2] INFO org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl - ignoreXmlConfiguration == true

Tags: websphere-8

I am migrating from WAS 7.0 to WAS 8.5 ,JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0 and richfaces 3.x to 4.x
I have various richfaces 4.3.x components used in my application.
whenever I try to use a  component, on-change I get the following error logged in my server console :-

[3/8/15 7:44:26:986 EDT] 00000089 SystemErr     R 373846 [WebContainer : 2] INFO org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl - ignoreXmlConfiguration == true

The response after the Ajax call on-change is also  very slow. I tried searching over different sites, but could not find a solution.

Thanks!